# Angular 6 second nested child route not working

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am making an experiment with following link.
https://angular.io/guide/router#the-sample-application

As you can see, there are several milestones to make routing.
During following these milestones, I met some bugs.
https://angular.io/guide/router#child-route-configuration
On this step, I couldn't go ahead because second route not working.

```
const crisisCenterRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'crisis-center',
    component: CrisisCenterComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: CrisisListComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: ':id',
            component: CrisisDetailComponent
          },
          {
            path: '',
            component: CrisisCenterHomeComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Second route is not working right now.

https://github.com/Js-Guru321/angular-router-sample
This is my code.

Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `<router-outlet>` to `crisis-list.html` and everything would work)
Each level of nested routes needs its own `router-outlet` tag inside of a parent route

```
<ul class="crises">
  <li *ngFor="let crisis of crises$ | async" [routerLink]="['/crisis-center', crisis.id]"
    [class.selected]="crisis.id === selectedId">
      <span class="badge">{{ crisis.id }}</span>{{ crisis.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: It is working good. I think router-outlet tag must be once in the crisis-center. Why would I put router-outlet twice? What's the reason?

Comment: the reason is in _nested_ routes, one is literally inside of a parent

Comment: What does that mean? Please tell me more by explaining with using code.